# Transition animation not working in iOS16 but was working in iOS15

Tags: ios, swift, animation, swiftui, ios16

I have a `SwiftUI` `Form` with a custom chart view (not *Swift Charts*). A long press toggles to a different type of chart. These charts use the `.transition(.slide)` modifier. In iOS 15 these transitioned as expected on a long press, but in iOS 16 they do not.

Persisted state property (an enum):

```
@AppStorage("chartType") var chartType: ChartType = .chartA
```

The `Form` part of the `body` property:

```
Form {
    
    // Other sections
    
    Section {
        switch chartType {
            case .chartA:
                ChartViewA()
                    .transition(.slide)
            case .chartB:
                ChartViewB()
                    .transition(.slide)
    }
        .onLongPressGesture {
            if chartType == .chartA {
                withAnimation {
                    summaryChartType = .chartB
                }
            } else {
                withAnimation {
                    summaryChartType = .chartA
                }
            }
        }
```

Unfortunately adding animation modifiers like `.animation(.spring(), value: chartType)` makes no difference.

I would be grateful for advice on why this might have worked in iOS 15 but not in iOS 16, and what I could do to restore animation here.

Comment: This might be an issue with `@AppStorage`.  Does the animation work correctly if `chartType` is `@State`?

Comment: @vacawama Thanks for the tip. I’ll check this when I’m at my computer. I thought `@AppStorage` behaved like `@State` (it certainly worked in iOS15). If that works, how could I persist the value? Would it be a `didSet` block, with loading from `UserDefaults` on `init()`?

Comment: I saw someone complaining that @AppStorage wasn’t animating correctly. I couldn’t reproduce it, but I had tried iOS 15 and your question makes me wonder that user was using iOS 16 and perhaps iOS 16 changed something about @AppStorage. If so, you could keep the @State var for animation and manually load/save it to user defaults. You have to use `.onChange {}` with `@State vars`.  `didSet` will not work.

Comment: @vacawama Great - thanks for the info. I’ll try it and update you later.

Comment: I have a related problem with `@AppStorage` in iOS 16. onChange is not triggered on an `@AppStorage` variable. It was working in iOS 15.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In iOS 16, there appears to be a problem with `@AppStorage` vars and animation.  Here is one possible workaround.  Use `@State` var for animation, and save it to an `@AppStorage` variable with `.onChange()`:

```
enum ChartType: String {
    case chartA, chartB
}

struct ChartViewA: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.red
    }
}

struct ChartViewB: View {
    var body: some View {
        Color.blue
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @AppStorage("chartType") var chartTypeAS: ChartType = .chartA
    @State private var chartType: ChartType = .chartA
    
    init() {
        // load initial value from persistent storage
        _chartType = State(initialValue: chartTypeAS)
    }
    
    var body: some View {

        Form {
            
            // Other sections
            
            Section {
                VStack {
                    switch chartType {
                    case .chartA:
                        ChartViewA()
                            .transition(.slide)
                    case .chartB:
                        ChartViewB()
                            .transition(.slide)
                    }
                }
                .onLongPressGesture {
                    if chartType == .chartA {
                        withAnimation {
                            chartType = .chartB
                        }
                    } else {
                        withAnimation {
                            chartType = .chartA
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .onChange(of: chartType) { value in
                // persist chart type
                chartTypeAS = value
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Tested in Xcode 14.0 with iPhone 14 simulator running iOS 16.

Alternatively, you could perform the saving to/restoring from `UserDefaults` manually.

Comment: Thank you! This certainly restores animation; the sections below move smoothly based on the different heights of the chart views and the charts themselves fade in. However, I still cannot get the transitions to work. Any idea what might be happening here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  In the example above, the views slide in, which shows they're using the transitions.  Can you expand on my example to show your issue?

Comment: So I think I must have something else in my view hierarchy interfering with the transition. Your example does work as expected, and certainly restores animation for me. Thanks.

Comment: Had the same problem today and i was thinking to bypass it like proposed solution. Is this a bug that Apple will fix?

Comment: @christostsang, I sure hope Apple fixes it.  It makes AppStorage less useful, but who knows how long that will take?

Comment: I opened a FB: FB11608015.

Comment: A similar problem appears with (at)Published and (at)Binding. The animation isn't as fluid and I get the error "Publishing changes from within view updates is not allowed, this will cause undefined behavior.".